# Android how do i disable checkbox during a long operation in PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, checkbox

I have this PreferenceScreen loaded from xml.
The thing is when i toggle the checkbox im starting a service withs
need like 5-10 sec to connect to a server.
How can i disable the checkbox during this time. 
Since the layout is inflated i cant see how to get checkbox.setEnable = false?

```
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="checkBoxenableincomingcall"
    android:title="Enable incoming call"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:summary="hasse running as background service" />
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="checkBoxmakephoneringonincoming"
    android:title="Dont ring on message"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:summary="dont disturb me" />
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="edittexvalue"
    android:title="EditText"
    android:summary="EditTextPreference" />
```

```
public class EditPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have your `PreferenceActivity` implement `OnPreferenceChangeListener` and then register your checkbox with it.  When you detect that it has been pressed disable the preference

```
//in onCreate
findPreference("checkboxpreferencekey").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);


public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue){
   if(preference.getKey().equals("checkboxpreferencekey")){
      preference.setEnabled(false);
      return true;
   }
   else return true;
}
```

That is how you can disable it, you will still need some sort of callback or broadcast from your service to know when to enable it again.  But when its time you do it the same way.

```
findPreference("checkboxpreferencekey").setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: It does not work im implementing like this 
implements OnPreferenceChangeListener .
Do i have to put something in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Erik if you at an @ username it sends a notification, I would have known to come back and help you!  Glad you got it working though!