# android- To force checkbox not to function from java code

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have a checkbox in my layout.I need to make it remained checked until a condition occurs.Unless that condition occurs I don't want to make the checkbox unchecked for the furthur clicks.ie, I want to make its functioning stopped.Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by using `setEnabled(false)` on your checkbox to make it untoggleable. More information can be found in other SO questions, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774916/android-how-do-i-disable-checkbox-during-a-long-operation-in-preferencescreen).